# How to manage the month and year dropdowns?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular10

I am having below requirement. Everything is working fine but when the change the year dropdown values it's[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1rJt.png) affecting the month values for another month dropdown. Can I get a solution for this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a minimal reproduction example in code. It's then way easier to help you. Read more about it stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Share also code you tried

Comment: you need use "differents" variables to each dropdown. I suppose you has a `*ngFor`, so create an array of object

Comment: yeah thanks. will check it out

Answer (score 0):

If you're making this in basic html, you would have

```
<select name="month">
  <option value="1">01</option>
  <option value="2">02</option>
  <!-- etc. etc. -->
</select>

<select name="year">
  <option value="1900">1900</option>
  <option value="1901">1901</option>
  <!-- etc. etc. -->
</select>

and those same <select> tags for the row underneath.
You would probably use html or php to fill in those <select> tags with <option> tags, so I don't see how by changing a value, some other value could change.
```